# how to hide/unhide elements while displaying hover

Tags: html, css

i'm displaying menu hover on image .These all image generated dynamically.
while mouse hover on first image menu will display but problem on menu items background items displaying. how to hide behide elemets while displying  hover ?

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #515151;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu li a {
    color: #515151;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px 15px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    background: #f44141;
    color: #fff;
}

.sub {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: none;
    padding: 40px 0 3px;
}

a.hover-link {
    width: 190px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #515151;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 110;
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px 0 1px 10px;
}

.sub-options {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the code.

Comment: please create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can we get more code? A jsfiddle perhaps? I tried my best to answer, but I don't know if that's your problem.

Comment: Still not enough code. We are hungry for dem codez. Feed us.

Comment: Are you asking how to hide/unhide background-images on :hover?

Comment: hi im very new to stackoverflow  just created my account in stackoverflow. i cant able to  paste full code in this blog.

Comment: I made one: http://jsfiddle.net/9YA9r/ It's kinda… not functional. Could you provide any code that your using that would complete it?

Comment: try to set z-index of layer which you are showing on hover and give background -color too.

Comment: @Era : thank you for replay and I have placed full sample code here http://jsfiddle.net/prasaddoddi/HjqYc/   i cant able to add this line <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HjqYc/2/) : This is just z-index's issue CSS:

```
.sub{
background: #fff;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
width: 200px;
margin: 0px 0 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #ddd;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
display: none; top:38px; left:0;
}
```

Comment: hi era ,its working for chrome but its not working with IE 8 any inputs?

Comment: problem was in ie7 not in ie8, of relative position. changed your code a bit. again click on working example link.

Comment: hi Era how to change this hover menu to on click menu. i have treid with .click function but its not working. any suggstions ?

Comment: yes its working on click menu but i cant able to remove menu when mouseout from menu or clicking on some where in page. any suggestions ?